# Get Page by TAG ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, tagging

so i have a php script that need to retrieve a certain "page", not a post but a page, in wordpress, i want to retreive ONE page that is pointed in a specific tag. I would like to know how i can retreive that certain page, the only parameter it needs is the tag->term_id.

I tried searching in google to acheive this. is this possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `WP_Query` with `post_type` set to `page` to query your database for pages. You can use the `tag_id` parameter to narrow down by tag. Limit it to one result using `posts_per_page` set to `1`.

```
//narrow down your query with $args
$args = array('post_type'=>'page', 'tag_id'=>3, 'posts_per_page'=>1);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query